# Find the In and out of the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table below and the system giving output and output which i don't wanted like this but the desired output as given below.

```
EmployeeID  TrxType TrxDateTime 
1              IN   20/07/2020 7:00 
1             OU    20/07/2020 18:00    
2             IN    21/07/2020 6:00 
2             OU    21/07/2020 17:30
```

System Output:-

```
employeeid  date    CheckIN            CheckOUT
1   20.07.2020        NULL           20/07/2020 18:00
1   20.07.2020     20/07/2020 7:00     NULL
2   21.07.2020        NULL           21/07/2020 17:30
2   21.07.2020     21/07/2020 6:00      NULL
```

This is the query I used:

```
select distinct(TimeBooking.employeeid),(convert(nvarchar(10), TimeBooking.PunchDateTime, 104)) as date,
    CheckIN = Max(case when TimeBooking.TrxType ='IN' then TimeBooking.trxDateTime END),
            CheckOUT = MAX(CASE WHEN TimeBooking.TrxType = 'OU' THEN TimeBooking.trxDateTime END)
            from TimeBooking where TimeBooking.TrxDateTime>='20-july-2020'  
    group by TimeBooking.TrxDateTime,employeeid
```

Desired Output:-

```
employeeid      date        CheckIN         CheckOUT
1           20.07.2020  20/07/2020 7:00   20/07/2020 18:00
2           21.07.2020  21/07/2020 6:00   21/07/2020 17:30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is only one row per employeeid per date, just use aggregation:

```
select employeeid, convert(date, TrxDateTime), min(TrxDateTime) as checkIN, max(TrxDateTime) as checkOUT
from t
group by employeeid, convert(date, TrxDateTime);
```

Edit:

If there are multiples rows per day per employee, you can "align" them by counting and then aggregating:

```
select employeeid, dte,
       min(case when trxType = 'IN' then TrxDateTime end) as checkIN,
       max(case when trxType = 'OU' then TrxDateTime end) as checkOUT
from (select t.*, convert(date, t.TrxDateTime) as dte,
             row_number() over (partition by t.employeeid, convert(date, t.TrxDateTime), t.trxType order by t.TrxDateTime) as seqnum
      from t 
     ) t
group by employeeid, dte, seqnum;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=68d3be2273d8f87b8ab061d11b14b26d) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: There are two or more row per employeeid

Comment: @kalaiselvanv And yet you provided a very simplistic and conveniently pure sample set. Go do your data analysis and verify that every IN has an associated OUT and that the pairs do NOT cross date boundaries.

Comment: @kalaiselvanv . . . That would be an entirely different question.  This answers the question that you have asked here.  You should ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.  You should also accept one of the answers here that answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an employee will only check in and out once a day, I'd self join the table based on the `TrxType`:

```sql
SELECT t1.EmployeeId, t1.TrxDateTime AS CheckIN, t2.TrxDateTime AS CheckOUT
FROM   TimeBooking t1
JOIN   TimeBooking t2 ON t1.TrxType = 'IN' AND
                         t2.TrxType = 'OUT' AND
                         t1.EmployeeId = t2.EmployeeId
```

Comment: Employeeid may not have only one CheckIN and One CheckOUT

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `PIVOT` operation for this. I hope you will be having multiple dates like this. So, I have accounted for the same.

```sql
declare @table table(EmployeeID int, TrxType char(2), TrxDateTime datetime)

set dateformat dmy
insert into @table values
(1             ,'IN',   '20/07/2020 7:00' )
,(1             ,'OU',   '20/07/2020 18:00')    
,(2             ,'IN',   '21/07/2020 6:00' )
,(2             ,'OU',   '21/07/2020 17:30')

SELECT EmployeeID, [Date], [IN] As CheckIn,[OU] AS checkout
 FROM (SELECT EmployeeID, cast(TrxDateTime as date) as [date],TrxType,TrxDateTime from @table) as t
PIVOT
(
min(TrxDateTime)
for TrxType in ([IN],[OU])
)as pvt
```

```
+------------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| EmployeeID |    Date    |         CheckIn         |        checkout         |
+------------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|          1 | 2020-07-20 | 2020-07-20 07:00:00.000 | 2020-07-20 18:00:00.000 |
|          2 | 2020-07-21 | 2020-07-21 06:00:00.000 | 2020-07-21 17:30:00.000 |
+------------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: this query is working, it is simple for four row to add manually, is there way to add automatically add from another table

Comment: @kalaiselvanv, i dont get your question. I would suggest you to post a separate question, if you have more questions, as changing answers will lead to confusion